# Sending message to queue in SingleActiveConsumer mode in MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have registered receive endpoint in SingleActiveConsumer mode. However I can't find a way to send a message directly to queue by using sendEndpoint. I receive following error:

```
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-single-active-consumer' for queue 'test' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'true' of type 'bool'',
```

I tried setting header "x-single-active-consumer"=true by using bus configurer:

```
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
            cfg.ConfigureSend(a => a.UseSendExecute(c => c.Headers.Set("x-single-active-consumer", true)));
        });
```

and directly on sendEndpoint:

```
        await sendEndpoint.Send(msg, context => {
                context.Headers.Set("x-single-active-consumer", true);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send directly to a receive endpoint in MassTransit, you can use the short address `exchange:test` instead, which will send to the exchange without trying to create/bind the queue to the exchange with the same name. That way, you decouple the queue configuration from the message producer.

Or, you could just use `Publish`, and let the exchange bindings route the message to the receive endpoint queue.